# Coordinates of android on-screen keyboard keys

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently working on an android project, and I need to find the coordinates of the keys on on-screen keyboard.

The only possible way I found was to create a custom keyboard, which I want to avoid.

Can anyone help me with suggestions? Is that even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is that even possible?" -- not really. After all, the input method does not need to have keys. And one app cannot monitor the UI of another app in most cases, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: I smell a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you just tell what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Murphy  I want to track physical precision of the user pressing the keys.

Comment: Sounds like you want a custom keyboard, if its something more than a "type after me" in which case you know what the correct letters are.

Comment: @James sorry I didn't explain in detail what I want to achieve. I want to keep track of how precisely the key is pressed with the finger of the user (the distance from the center of the key to where the key is pressed).

Comment: Are the touch points even available to the app, if within the keyboard? Well, if they are, a fallback could be to have the user go through a calibration step. Just shooting off ideas.